# VB Listview second column starts from first column last line

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, listview

I want to input info in my listview column 1 and column 2. I get the information I want in column 1 and 2 but the information in column 2 will start at the last line of column 1. I want that column 2 also starts from the top. Hope you understand what I mean, here a screenshot [image: here a screenshot]

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("""ID"".*""")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd)

   For Each itemcode As Match In matches

            Dim Col1 As String = itemcode.Value.Split(":").GetValue(1)
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
            lvi.Text = Col1
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
        Next     

Dim r2 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("""ID"".*""")
Dim matches2 As MatchCollection = r2.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd)

   For Each itemcode2 As Match In matches2

            Dim Col2 As String = itemcode2.Value.Split(":").GetValue(1)
            Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
            lvi.SubItems.Add(Col2)
            ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
       Next
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: add the col2 information as subitems to the existing ListViewitems (dont create new ones) or better add them at the same time so you dont mess up the order

Comment: I'm sorry but can't find the solution. Tried to search it but no luck.

Comment: You only listed a code fragment. which wont compile.  anyone who wants to help has to *guess* what the FOR statement looks like.

Comment: I have updated my code. Hope it is more clear now.

Comment: So you want one column populated for the first Regex match set and two columns on the second?

Comment: @NoAlias First Regex match for 1st column second regex match for second column.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in your second method you are spinning through the same list as the first one (or a list with the same count), the following code will work.  This is taking the suggestion of Plutonix and adding subitems to the already created ListItems.

```
    Dim intCursor As Integer = 0
    Do While intCursor < lstYourList.Count

        'Assumes your list is called lstYourList
        Dim strSubItemToAdd As String = lstYourList(intCursor).Value.Split(":").GetValue(1)

        ListView1.Items(intCursor).SubItems.Add(strSubItemToAdd)

        intCursor += 1

    Loop
```

If you insist on keeping your For Each iteration of the Regex Matches (per comments to original answer) then it would be closer to this:

```
Dim intCursor As Integer

For Each itemcode2 As Match In YourRegex.Matches(strSource)

    ListView1.Items(intCursor).SubItems.Add(itemcode2.Value.Split(":").GetValue(1))

    intCursor += 1

Next
```

Okay, let me take one more stab at it based on your comments.  I altered your code above so that it will add the second list of Regex Matches to the second column.  You'll notice that I only add a new ListViewItem if we've gone past the total number of ListViewItems in the ListView.  Otherwise, I just added them as SubItems.

```
Dim r As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("""ID"".*""")
Dim matches As MatchCollection = r.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd)

For Each itemcode As Match In matches

    Dim Col1 As String = itemcode.Value.Split(":").GetValue(1)
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
    lvi.Text = Col1
    ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)

Next     

Dim r2 As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("""ID"".*""")
Dim matches2 As MatchCollection = r2.Matches(sr.ReadToEnd)

Dim intCursor As Integer

For Each itemcode2 As Match In matches2

    Dim Col2 As String = itemcode2.Value.Split(":").GetValue(1)

    If intCursor = ListView1.Items.Count Then

        ListView1.Items(intCursor).SubItems.Add(Col2)

    Else

        Dim lvi2 As New ListViewItem
        lvi2.SubItems.Add(Col2)

        ListView1.Items.Add(lvi2)       

    End If

    intCursor += 1

Next
```

Comment: Instead of using a For Each to spin through your Regex Matches, replace it with the Do Loop.  Or keep the For Each, but keep the cursor to add the SubItem to the correct ListViewItem.

Comment: @Mathijs I have edited the answer.  If the latest edit (see bottom of answer) isn't what you're looking for, the complete answer provided should be enough information to help you achieve what you're trying to accomplish on your own.

Comment: I appreciated all of your help. Tried your code but it is not working.

Comment: Do you mind elaborating?  I used this code using example lists (all three blocks) and it worked.

Comment: The results are still looking wrong, like on the screenshot.